# Pine Script v5 - daily ranges on a 30min chart... stop plotting current day?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
//@version=5
indicator('ECW - D', overlay=true)

//ATR lookback
atr_5 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', ta.atr(5))

//Get daily close
daily_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)

//Range calculations
eH = daily_close + atr_5 * 0.8
eL = daily_close - atr_5 * 0.8
eHt = daily_close + atr_5 * 0.6
eLt = daily_close - atr_5 * 0.6
zcH = daily_close + atr_5 * 0.28
zcL = daily_close - atr_5 * 0.28

//Range plots
plot(eH, color=#ffffff50, title='High', style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(eL, color=#ffffff50, title='Low', style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(eHt, color=#67666650, title='High (t)', style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(eLt, color=#67666650, title='Low (t)', style=plot.style_stepline)

//Variables for bar coloring
var int lastBarOfDay = na
var bool entryzone_occurred = false
isNewDay = ta.change(time("D")) != 0
if isNewDay
    lastBarOfDay := bar_index + 12
    entryzone_occurred := false

//Barcolor qualifiers
is_outside_ecw = close > eH or close < eL
is_entryzone = ((high >= eHt and close <= eH) or (low <= eLt and close >= eL)) and bar_index != lastBarOfDay
is_zoneclose = (low <= zcH and high >= zcL)

if is_entryzone
    entryzone_occurred := true

//Bar coloring
barcolor(is_entryzone ? color.rgb(202, 108, 231, 28) : na)
barcolor(is_zoneclose and entryzone_occurred ? color.rgb(85, 233, 159, 31) : na)
barcolor(is_outside_ecw and entryzone_occurred ? color.rgb(236, 72, 72, 8) : na)
```

Everything works as intended except for how the most recent ranges are plotted. It continuously adjusts to the live data (see screenshot). I assume its because of how I've defined 'daily_close', each new bar's close is interpreted as the current day's close.

I only want the new range plotted once the current day closes, whether that's redefining 'daily_close' as the last 30min bar close or restricting the script from plotting until 16:00 EST or whatever else.

I've tried these methods and others but can't escape the study/compiling errors.

Thanks in advance.